# Can't get the table to iterate rows

Tags: javascript

I'm brand new to javascript so this is probably really dumb... but I have no idea why I can't get the script to place the new table rows vertically... this code seems to append all new rows horizontally with the first row.

```
function genGameGrid(){
var rows=10, columns=10;
var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
document.body.appendChild(x);

    for(var i=0;i<=rows;i++){
       var y = document.createElement("TR");
       y.setAttribute("id", "myTr", i);
       document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(y);
       for(var j=0;j<=columns;j++){
           var z = document.createElement("TD");
           var t = document.createTextNode(j);
           z.appendChild(t);
           document.getElementById("myTr").appendChild(z);
       }
   }  
}
```

I think it has to do with setting the attributes of var y, but have no idea... Any help would be appreciated!

After the help I learned where I was messing up. Here is the functioning code:

```
function genGameGrid(){
var rows=10, columns=10;
var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
document.body.appendChild(table);

 for(var i=0;i<=rows;i++){
   var row = document.createElement("TR");
   table.appendChild(row);

   for(var j=0;j<=columns;j++){
       var cell = document.createElement("TD");
       var text = document.createTextNode("");
       cell.appendChild(text);
       row.appendChild(cell);
   }
```

}
}

Answer (score 3):

`.setAttribute` doesn't accept 3 parameters:

```
y.setAttribute("id", "myTr", i);
```

You are probably trying to concatenate the 2 values?

```
y.setAttribute("id", "myTr" + i);
```

Also you don't have horizontal rows. You are appending all the cells to the first row that has `myTr` attribute! You are generating rows with same `id` attribute and `.getElementById` returns the first matching element.

And you don't need to add an attribute to an element and query the DOM for getting the same element by ID. Think twice. `y` refers to the current row. You can simply code:

```
y.appendChild(z);
```

Comment: Some of the troubles of learning is not knowing how to describe what you're trying to do. I don't know why I got hung up on set attribute. You're advice on querying the DOM really helped! I got it working after removing the .getElementById() calls.